# Como asignar el resultado de un select de una tabla a diferentes variables

Tags: php, pdo

Realizo la consulta:

```
  SELECT cat_img, descripcion FROM `CAT_PRODUCTO` WHERE id_gal BETWEEN 1 AND 7
```

Ahora quiero asignar el resultado a diferentes variables acorde al `id_gal`

ejemplo:

```
   $catimg_1: imagen extraída del registro id_gal 1

   $catimg_2: imagen extraída del registro id_gal 2
```

y así sucesivamente todo esto con **PHP PDO**
espero ser claro con mis dudas.
agradeceré cualquier ayuda

Answer (score 0):

Podes utilizar [`extract($array);`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.extract.php) que expande un array a variables.

Armas el array con un while y luego el extract, algo así:

```
<?php

$result = [];
$sql = "SELECT id_gal, cat_img, descripcion 
        FROM `CAT_PRODUCTO` 
        WHERE id_gal BETWEEN 1 AND 7";
$sth = $conn->prepare($sql);
$sth->execute() or die($sth->errorInfo());
while ($row = $sth->fetch(PDO::FETCH_OBJ)) :
     $result["catimg_".$row->id_gal] = $row->cat_img;
endwhile;

var_dump($result);

extract($result);

echo "catimg_1: ".$catimg_1.PHP_EOL;
echo "catimg_2: ".$catimg_2.PHP_EOL;
echo "catimg_3: ".$catimg_3.PHP_EOL;

?>
```